# Is there a way to change a toast's color and text size/color, but retain the system toast layout?

Tags: android, toast, android-xml

I know that I could do all of this easily with a custom toast layout, but in creating a custom layout, I would no longer be using the system's default toast view.

Example: Toasts of course look different in Android 2.2 vs Android 4.0.  If I create a custom view for my toast, then it will look the exact same in both versions, but what I want is for it to retain its... "Androidiness" for lack of a better word.  Basically, does anyone know of a default toast XML layout?  Is that even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the default layout used by `Toasts`.

**transient_notification**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/toast_frame">

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Small"
    android:textColor="@color/bright_foreground_dark"
    android:shadowColor="#BB000000"
    android:shadowRadius="2.75"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**These are the enter and exit animations**

**ENTER**

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@interpolator/decelerate_quad"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

**EXIT**

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@interpolator/accelerate_quad" 
        android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

**toast_frame_holo.9** is the name of the resource used for the background. Search the SDK to find all of the sizes.

[**And here is the full source for `Toasts`**](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/Toast.java)

If you're unsure about any of that, search the SDK for all of the resources, that's where I looked.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to answer my question.  This would still make the toast look the same regardless of platform though, but I guess I can't avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

On my ICS device I recently had a message fail to send due to loss of connection. It looked like a toast but had a different font size, was two lines long, and had a red border. It basically said that the message failed to send (or connection error).

That might be similar to what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to retain the default toast too but found solution which showed me how to create a single toast layout for all system. So I created this helper. I know, it's a hack, but it works fine for me.

Here I added an image to the toast in front of the text without touching its native appearance. You could easily modify the text color and size here.

Maybe someone might be interested in this code snippet...

```
private static Toast makeImageToast(int imageResId, CharSequence text, int duration) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, text, duration);

    View rootView = toast.getView();
    LinearLayout linearLayout = null;
    TextView messageTextView = null;

    // check (expected) toast layout
    if (rootView instanceof LinearLayout) {
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView;

        if (linearLayout.getChildCount() == 1) {
            View child = linearLayout.getChildAt(0);

            if (child instanceof TextView) {
                messageTextView = (TextView) child;
            }
        }
    }

    // cancel modification because toast layout is not what we expected
    if (linearLayout == null || messageTextView == null) {
        // failed to create image toast layout, using usual toast
        return toast;
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams textParams = messageTextView.getLayoutParams();
    ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) textParams).gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;

    // convert dip dimension
    int imageSize = dipToPixel(25);
    int imageMargin = dipToPixel(15);

    // setup image view layout parameters
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(imageSize, imageSize);
    imageParams.setMargins(0, 0, imageMargin, 0);
    imageParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;

    // setup image view
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setId(TOAST_IMAGE_ID);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageResId);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(imageParams);

    // modify root layout
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    linearLayout.addView(imageView, 0);

    return toast;
}

public static int dipToPixel(float dip) {
    return (int) (dip * mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
}
```